# Trouble with facebook's pay dialogue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
An error occurred with *****. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

Hi guys. The error message above is an example of what I receive when trying to integrate facebook's pay dialogue with my app. I am aware that this error occurs when there is a discrepancy between the url domain you provide to facebook and the url you place in your redirect uri variable. However, in this situation, the url's match exactly.

```
Site Url:     www.vgiver.com/
Site Domain:     www.vgiver.com/
Redirect_uri value:     redirect_uri=    vgiver.com/&
                         credits_purchase=false&
                         order_info=ORDER_ID
```

Can anyone help me to understand why I still receive this API error? Any help would be appreciated, I really need to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by default: `www.domain.com` **DOES NOT** equal `domain.com`

So change your Site Domain (App Domain) to:  `vgiver.com` (without `www`)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried what you suggested and still does not seem to be helping. Could it possibly be a problem with the fact that I do not own an SSL certificate for my domain?